# CryptoJS AES and Java AES encrypted value mismatch

Tags: java, javascript, aes, cryptojs

I am trying to encrypt in client and decrypt in sever using AES,
    so using cryptojs to encrypt in client side with CBC mode and nopadding
    in server side also using `Cipher` class with same mode and nopadding

```js
function call()
{
  var key = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse('roshanmathew1989');
  var iv  = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse('roshanmathew1989');
  var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("roshanmathew1989",key,{ iv: iv},
      {padding:CryptoJS.pad.NoPadding});
  alert(encrypted.ciphertext.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64));
  alert(encrypted.iv.toString());
}
```

Server side code

```java
public class Crypto
{ 

  private static byte[] key = null;

  public void setKey(String key){this.key=key.getBytes();}

  public String encrypt(String strToEncrypt)
  {
    String encryptedString =null;
    try
    {
      Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");
      final SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key,"AES");
      System.out.println("sdfsdf = "+key.toString());
      IvParameterSpec ips = new IvParameterSpec(key);
      cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey,ips);
      encryptedString = Base64.encodeBase64String(cipher.doFinal(strToEncrypt.getBytes()));
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
      System.out.println(" ERROR : "+e.getMessage());
    }
    return encryptedString;

  } other method omitted ....
```

implementation

```
Crypto cry=new Crypto();
cry.setKey("roshanmathew1989");
String s=cry.encrypt("roshanmathew1989");
```

Results

```
Browser side value =       O64X/bKNBu7R2Tuq2lUbXeFlQ7wD2YnFasyyhsVUryw=
Server side value of s =   RrNcVIER/75fzdjHr884sw==
```

Can anybody point out the mistake?

Comment: Your server side output is 16 bytes in length, which is correct. For some reason, your browser-side value is 32 bytes.

Comment: thanks still not clear am i doing something wrong

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things wrong with the code:

- you are using hexadecimal decoding of the key in JavaScript, and `String.getBytes()` - character encoding without specifying the character set - in Java
- your key is 16 characters (it should be 16, 24 or 32 randomized *bytes*), but it is not in hexadecimals
- you are encrypting instead of decrypting on the "server side", although that one is probably on purpose

Take another good look on how to perform encoding and character-encoding, they are essential for good crypto and often performed incorrectly (it's probably the most common issue on Stackoverflow regarding encryption)

Comment: thanks for the correction , i am using rhino to run crypto js  in server side , since encrypting and decrypting using the same source is better option.

Comment: Glad you found another option. Be aware that using JavaScript for encryption purposes may slow down your server application considerably (when used on a large amounts of bytes). Without going into a performance battle, JavaScript is considerably slower than Java, which in turn is considerably slower than a native solution for cryptography related functionality. Please do not abandon the question because you found another option, the question is still valid.